# How do I get rid of paragraph tags in CKEditor from CDN

Tags: ckeditor5

I'm running CKEditor from the CDN, and when I retrieve data from Database it comes with paragraph tags, and this breaks my page structure. Any help?

Comment: You didn't provide many details of what is in the database and what is the editor output but my guess is that you are trying to run CKEditor 5 on a block which is not a paragraph, which is currently impossible. That's why the editor auto–paragraphs all the content (`paragraph` is the default block in the editor model). If that's the case, check out the [issue](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/762) and leave .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, all I had to do is use

```
{!! $row->uid !!}
```

instead of:

```
{{!! $row->uid !!}}
```